# how to do globalization in a website mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a website that supports several languages​​, including Spanish, English and French, but I want the user to select the language with a button and without placing it in the queryString, ie without `http://site.com/{lang}`.

If you could help me with a tutorial to do it in MVC 4 with RazorEngine I would greatly appreciate

Comment: See [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32764989)

Answer (score 0):

look here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Code52.i18n.MVC4 and here http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/tutorial.html for the tutorial.
It may help to give you a start.